solution-verification | What is the maximum number of distinct planes determined by three of the 25 points?
The problem
Consider a plane $\alpha$, a line $d || \alpha$, five points $A,B,C,D,E$, any 3 non-collinear located on the $\alpha$ plane and the points $P_1,P_2,... , P_20$ distinct two by two, located on $d $. What is the maximum number of distinct planes determined by three of the 25 points, excluding the $\alpha$ plane?
my idea
So one plane is made by 3 noncollinear points:

If all the 3 points are on a plane $\alpha$ then the plane made is always $\alpha$ we won't count this plane because the problem tells us to do so

If 2 point are on $\alpha$ and one on line $d$. For this, we have 10 combinations for the 2 points from $\alpha$ and 20 other points from d. This will make $200=20*10$ distinct planes

If one point is from $\alpha$ and the other from line $d$. Then for everypoint of $\alpha$ we will only have 1 unique plane, because the points from $d$ are collinear and $d || \alpha$

If all point are from line $d$, then will not be any planes, because all the points are collinear


I got that the results is 205 planes.
I put this as solution verification because I'm not sure on case 2), because I'm not sure if all of those 200 planes are distinct.
Hope one of you can help me! Thanks!

200 planes are distinct all right. It is the 5 which may partially coincide, in case any pair of points from $A, B, C, D, E$ sits on a line parallel to $d$, which the problem statement did not exclude.

@IvanNeretin Yeah, it's not excluded, but we need the maximum of planes. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Why the down vote? I would apreciate that woever downvoted to explain why...

Oh yes, they ask for the maximum. Then your reasoning sounds good to me.

@IvanNeretin Do you think its alright how I explained point 3, or do I need to add some other explanation?
